# Not getting proper data while join two queries in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a query one query getting weekly data one is getting yesterday record from same table. When I execute both queries separately, they are working properly, but when join both queries, then yesterday's data query is not returning the proper output.

Sample data:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a678d12df7643000838c2f442d4d85a

**Query #1**: weekly data

```
SELECT 
    temp2.driver_id, temp2.driver_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT temp2.car_number) AS car_number,
    SUM(temp2.day1_trips) AS day1_trips,
    SUM(temp2.day2_trips) AS day2_trips,
    sum(temp2.day3_trips) as day3_trips,
    sum(temp2.day4_trips) as day4_trips,
    sum(temp2.day5_trips) as day5_trips,
    sum(temp2.day6_trips) as day6_trips,
    sum(temp2.day7_trips) as day7_trips,
    sum(temp2.trips) as total_trips,
    sum(temp2.revenue) as total_revenue,
    sum(temp2.online_hours) as total_online_hours
FROM
    (SELECT 
         temp1.driver_id, temp1.driver_name,
         temp1.car_number, temp1.car_id,
         temp1.trips, temp1.revenue, temp1.online_hours,
         CASE 
             WHEN temp1.date = '2022-04-04' 
                 THEN temp1.trips 
                 ELSE 0 
         END AS day1_trips,
case when temp1.date='2022-04-05' then temp1.trips else 0 end as day2_trips,
case when temp1.date='2022-04-06' then temp1.trips else 0 end as day3_trips,
case when temp1.date='2022-04-07' then temp1.trips else 0 end as day4_trips,
case when temp1.date='2022-04-08' then temp1.trips else 0 end as day5_trips,
case when temp1.date='2022-04-09' then temp1.trips else 0 end as day6_trips,
case when temp1.date='2022-04-10' then temp1.trips else 0 end as day7_trips
from
(
   SELECT date,driver_id,driver_name,car_number,car_id,trips,revenue,online_hours
   FROM fleet_driver_dash_daily 
   WHERE  team_id=1 and (date BETWEEN '2022-04-04' and '2022-04-10'))as temp1
) as temp2 
GROUP by temp2.driver_id
```

**Query #2**: yesterday's data:

```
SELECT driver_id,
SUM(CASE date WHEN subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN trips ELSE 0 END) AS yesterday_trips,
SUM(CASE date WHEN subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN online_hours ELSE 0 END) AS yesterday_online,
SUM(CASE date WHEN subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS yesterday_revenue
FROM fleet_driver_dash_daily
WHERE team_id=1 
GROUP BY driver_id
```

**expected output,**

| driver_id | car_number | day1_trip | day2_trip | day3_trip | day4_trip | day5_trip | yesterday_trip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 00001 | 7 | 0 | 8 | 0 |  | 10 |
| 20 | 00002 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 5 | 0 |

Comment: Can you put some of your data on any online db fiddle?
would help us!

Comment: What do you mean by "join the two queries together"? What do you mean by "not getting proper output" - what is the output you are getting and what is the issue with it?

Comment: @Asgar I have added sampal data

Comment: @NickW basically first query get weekly data and second query get yesterday data i want join the two queries together , i have mention on question my excepted output.

Comment: Do you mean actually join the queries together or do you mean write one query that returns the same data as the two original queries do? Those are two very different questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want

```
 SELECT sub1.*, sub2.yesterday_trip
 FROM (
   -- put contents of first query here
 ) as sub1
 LEFT JOIN (
   -- put contents of second query herre
 ) as sub2 on sub1.driver_id = sub2.driver_id
```

Is there any reason this did not work?